# Creating a unique file name by calculating the seconds from a set date to the time now.

Tags: php

After reading a few threads and articles I came up with the following code:

```
$timeFirst  = strtotime('1971-01-01 00:00:00');
$timeSecond = date("s");
$filename = $timeFirst - $timeSecond;
```

I basically want a unique number to use as a filename, and as the seconds from the set date to now will never be the same, this seemed like a good option. However the number is going down, which unless im moving backwards through time (unlikely) isn't correct. Can anyone tell me why my syntax is wrong?

Comment: i dun get what is your Objective for doing this. The existing function like uniqid, tempnam is not good enough? If I wanna to stick to this by number, I will use mcirotime(true) in microsecond

Answer (score 0):

for giving a unique file name just append the actual file name with time().

for e.g if file name is dummy.png then append the "dummy" with time();

$file_name= "dummy".time();

the $file_name will give you a unique file name.